# Crear una funcion para hallar porciento y me envia eror de sintaxis. Que puede ser?

Tags: excel

Soy nuevo en VBA, pero tengo necesidad de crear una función que me halle el 3% y el 5% a un salario determinado con ciertas condiciones.
Por ejemplo: El salario es de 4210.00 (puede ser cualquier otro), pero el 3% se le halla a la diferencia entre este numero y 3260.00.

```
Public Funtction TresPor ()
TresPor=(¨salario¨-3260.00)*3.0*100
End Funtction
```

Por supuesto que esto no esta terminado. El 5% se le haya al Salario. Esta parte aun no le he escrito.
Lo otro es que el valor final debe ser >= 0 porque no debe quedar en negativo.

Comment: Hablo desde la ignorancia, pero no será más fácil hacer ("salario"-3260,00)*1'03 ?

Comment: salario es un string.. que se supone que va ahi?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El error de sintaxis podría ser porque tienes puesto `Funtction` en vez de `Function`?

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente debe ser Function, en lugar de Function.
Te propongo reajustar el código como sigue:

```
            Public Function TresPor (Salario As Double)  As Double
            Dim calculo As Double
            calculo = Salario*0.03
            TresPor = calculo
            End Function
```

En este caso la función es Pública y se llama TresPor. La parte (Salario As Double) indica que la función recibe un parámetro de tipo Double (Double es un tipo de datos numérico e indica que contendrá un número quizas con decimales ). La parte que dice As Double, indica que el resultado de la fórmula también será de tipo Double.

Dim calculo As Double, declara la variable llamada calculo y que será también de tipo Double. la línea calculo = Salario * 0.03, realiza el calculo de la fórmula multiplicando por 0.03 el valor que se recibe como parámetro y lo almacena en la variable calculo. El valor 0.03 indica que es el tres por ciento. Si quieres que sea un 5% entonces debes poner 0.05 y por supuesto cambiar el nombre de la función a CincoPor, por ejemplo.

Finalmente en la línea TresPor = calculo, indica que la función regresa el valor almacenado en la variable calculo (esto es el resultado Salario * 0.03).
Y por último terminas con End Function